# errors in load data infile syntax

Tags: mysql

The following mysql syntax failed to execute, giving errors "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' at line 1". I am using Mysql version 5.5.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/path/../notepad.txt' INTO TABLE data (url) LINES TERMINATED BY '\r';
```

I need to get rid of '\r' after each data value in my 'url' column.

```
(1, 'http://new.index100.html\r', 4, '2014-07-22 15:27:28'),
(2, 'http://new.index100.html\r', 4, '2014-07-22 15:27:28'),
(3, 'http://new.index300.html\r', 4, '2014-07-22 15:27:28'),
```

I have tried both '\r' and '\r\n', but without LINES TERMINATED syntax it has worked fine.

Here is a glimpse of my notepad.txt

```
http://new.index100.html
http://new.index200.html
http://new.index300.html
http://new.index400.html ..and so on
```

Comment: Maybe use MySQL's [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) function if you want to remove them from inside your column, as you state - *"I need to get rid of '\r' after each data value in my 'url' column."*

Comment: Just try `\n\r`, or just `\n`. It's generally LF, CR or CRLF.

Comment: with \n\r it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fields escaped by '\\'` along with your command; like

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\\Test\\data.txt' 
INTO TABLE tab 
fields escaped by '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r';
```

So for your particular case it should be as below

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\path\\..\\notepad.txt' 
INTO TABLE data(url) 
fields terminated by ','
escaped by '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r';
```

Comment: @user3858368, did you tried this suggestion? does it help?